# command to see the total installed packages in Slackware?

Tags: command-line, package-management, slackware

I need to show the total but I have only found the command to list the installed packages with this:

```
ls -l /var/log/packages/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `wc -l` will print the total line count. Pipe your `ls` content into it using

```
ls /var/log/packages | wc -l
```

This will give you the total number of packages installed in /var/log/packages. 
The reason I left out `-l` in my command was because in most cases that will print the total block count at the top of the directory listing, which would contribute to your end line count.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following comment in `installpkg`, it might be more future-proof to get information about installed packages from `/var/lib/pkgtools/packages/` rather than `/var/log/packages`:

```
# Mon Jun  4 21:17:58 UTC 2018
# Migrate the package database and directories from /var/log to
# /var/lib/pkgtools. /var/log was never a good place for this data, as it is
# considered by many to be a directory that could be wiped to free up some
# space.
```

As of the time this post was written, it looks like `/var/log/packages` is symlinked to `/var/lib/pkgtools/packages/` so it will still work for now but it's unclear whether this link is designed to be temporary or permanent meaning it's likely safest to bypass the link entirely.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun 14  2022 /var/log/packages -> ../lib/pkgtools/packages/
```